# Section fixed header overlapping scrollbar

Tags: html, css, header, scrollbar, overlap

i'm pretty new to html and css. Browsed through previously asked similar questions but non of the solutions seems to work for me. Basically I have this situation:

[Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyKKF.png).

The desired effect is the content to be visible through the semi-transparent header, but the header shouldn't overlap the scrollbar.

HTML is

```
<body>
    <div class="flex">
        <nav>

        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <header>

            </header>
            <div class="content">
                some random text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS is

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex{
    display: flex;
}

nav{
    flex: 0 0 20rem;
    background-color: black;
    height: 90vh;
}

.container{
    background-color: blue;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

header{
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 20rem;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}
.content{
    height: 2000px;
    color: white;
}

footer{
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Only solution I've found is to put a value into header {right} equal to the width of the scrollbar, but that's of course not reliable for all browsers, so it's just a trick, not a real solution.

Tried using sticky but that way header doesn't overlap content as desired.

Tried to put header directly inside content but it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, there is no CSS only solution. You have to add JS. Here is the code.

```
<div class="flex">
    <nav>

    </nav>
    <div class="container" id="cntnr">
        <header id="hdr">

        </header>
        <div class="content">
            some random text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex{
    display: flex;
}

nav{
    flex: 0 0 20rem;
    background-color: black;
    height: 90vh;
}

.container{
    background-color: blue;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.container.sticky{
    padding-top:0px;
}

header{
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position:absolute;


}
header.sticky{position:sticky;top:0}
.content{
    height: 2000px;
    color: white;
}

footer{
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cntnrScrll = document.getElementById("cntnr");
    var hdr = document.getElementById("hdr");

cntnrScrll.onscroll = function()  { scrollFunction() };

function scrollFunction() {
  if (cntnrScrll.scrollTop > 0 ) {
    hdr.classList.add("sticky");
    cntnrScrll.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    hdr.classList.remove("sticky");
    cntnrScrll.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's my fear. Unfortunately is part of an exercise and i'm allowed to use html and css only. I'm trying to figure it out but everything I'm trying is not working. I'll wait a bit just to see if someone has a working method with css only. If that's not the case i'll accept your answer as correct.

Comment: In that case, change these properties. I don't know why I thought it earlier! 
 .container{padding-top: 0px;}
header{position:sticky;left:0;}

Comment: Thank you, this last thing works perfectly fine. I was sure i'd already tried this, but surely padding in the content made me think it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

you can add z-index on the .container so its scrollbar will be shown over the rest of the elements:

(notice: a position which is not static (the default) is also needed for z-index to work)

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: blue;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

I put a 100 so you can also add z-index on other elements in between. but also 1 will do the effect for now

Comment: Tried but doesn't work for me https://ibb.co/92gRB9b.
Also correct if i'm wrong, but .container has no position:absolute nor has flex so z-index should have no effect on it.

Comment: It needs to have a position that isn't static (the default), so position: relative; would be enough for the z-index (thanks for highlighting it)

Comment: Found a workoround with your method. Only thing, in this case the background-color should be in an outer container, while .container should have transparent (default) background. In this case I used background color in the body and it worked. Thank You!

Comment: Ok not true, it looked like it was working, but it was optical illusion.
When passing on text looked fine https://ibb.co/ck8n6y4

But when adding content I realized it's not a see through, but content actually goes above the header https://ibb.co/wBhrQCg. And it's natural since now it has higher z-index than the header.